# Cut through overlay in CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, overlay

What I'm trying to do is cut through a transparent overlay placed above a video (check example below). What makes it a bit specific is that the "hole" itself is not a basic shape such as a square or a circle.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKnm8.jpg)

I tried dabbling with css masking but I have to admit I'm not a fan of its support. I currently see two possible solutions:
 1. Placing another video on top and masking it
 2. Using a precut image and placing it over the video

An ideal solution would work cross-browser, of course. All I can say is that I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? You need to provide a [Minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do understand that providing at least a working example would help out, but a verifiable example is out of context here since I myself am struggling to find a solution.

I don't have a piece of code that needs to be looked at to fix a certain issue - I have an issue trying to write that piece of code. What I'm asking is advice since this is something I never ran into before now.

That being said, I will try coming up with something over the next few days, hopefully I'll be able to provide a minimal example. 

P.S. sorry for a late response.